# Can anyone help me change this code from AS2 to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

This will be a simple clock. I've been using AS2 since I learned Flash in early 2000s. It's time to move on.

```
for (a=1; a<60; a++) {
    duplicateMovieClip("dot0", "dot"+a, 10+a);
    _root["dot"+a]._rotation = a*6;
    _root["dot"+a].gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Comment: Please, post your trial, so we can discuss about error generated by your code

Comment: Like Joe said... show what you've tried for AS3 and we will help you fix that. Im too far from AS2 now to even remember it. That code gives me a headache. What is this `_root["dot"+a]._rotation = a*6;` doing exactly? How do you place 10 dots to represent 60 minutes?? Anyways look up how to draw a circle (`sprite` & `.graphics`) as variable then also how to addchild "instances" of a variable into a "clockface" container MC...

Comment: The a*6 is because 60 minutes = 360 degrees, so each minute is 6 degrees. I assume that 'a' is just an iterator variable like i.

Comment: Yeah I see it now... Dunno why I thought `a` was being adjusted (incremented / divided) within the loop itself cos that would affect `for (a=1; a<60; a++)`. I was confused, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe published [ActionScript 2.0 Migration](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~eliens/pim/assets/flex3/langref/migration.html) that helped me tremendously back in the day.

Some specifics related to your code:

- Properties aren't prefixed with underscores, ex `_rotation` is now `rotation`, and `_root` is now `root`.
- `root` is not global, it is a property of display objects, and it is `null` if the display object is not in the display list.
- `duplicateMovieClip` does not exist anymore. You should export your symbol to a class and use [`new` operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#new) and [`addChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()) to create an instance and add it to the display, ex:

  ```
  var dot:Dot = new Dot();
  addChild(dot);
  ```
- Display objects created in code are not automatically given a `name` and assigned to a property on its parent when added to the display. You can set the `name` and use [`getChildByName`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()) on its parent. Example:

  ```
  var dot:Dot = new Dot();
  dot.name = "dot" + i;
  addChild(dot);

  var n:int = 10;
  var dot10:Dot = getChildByName("dot" + n) as Dot;
  ```

But this is a bit cumbersome, so in most cases it makes more sense to just store your display objects in your own array and reference them by index:

```
    var dots:Array = [];

    var dot:Dot = new Dot();
    addChild(dot);
    dots.push(dot);

    var firstDot:Dot = dots[0];
```

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help here and elsewhere, this is what works for me:

```
var i:Number = 1;
var dots:Array = [];
for (i=0; i<60; i++) {

var dot:Dot = new Dot;

addChild(dot);
dots.push(dot);

dot.x=683;
dot.y=436;
dot.rotation = i*6;
dot.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

The clock I'm making don't have hands but the dots change color for the hours minutes and seconds. Thanks everybody who helped